# Помогите пожалуйста реализовать функцию

Tags: python, строки

Пожалуйста помогите реализовать данную функцию.

```
 def reverse_subword(s: str, subword: str) -> str:
"""
If subword exists in s, reverse the first occurrence of s and return the modified string.
Otherwise return original s.
reverse_subword("abcde", "bc") => "acbde"
reverse_subword("abcabc", "bc") => "acbabc"
reverse_subword("abcabc", "ac") => "abcabc"
:param s: original string
:param subword: len(subword) > 0
:return:
"""
pass
```

**У меня не проходит 3 тестер **

```
assert reverse_subword("tere", "ab") == "tere"
assert reverse_subword("tere", "te") == "etre"
assert reverse_subword("teretere", "te") == "etretere"
```

Мой код

```
if subword in s:
    reversed = subword[-1::-1]
    return s.replace(subword, reversed)
else:
    return s
```

Comment: откуда задача? В условии очевидная и явная ошибка, неужели до сих пор никто не заметил?

Comment: @Эникейщик мутные условия. Я бы сказал, что они не совсем корректно сформулированы. Если Вы про второй кейс, то скорее он говорит, что ревирсить надо только первое вхождение.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Да понятные условия. Кроме того, что вместо  *reverse the first occurrence of s* очевидно должно быть *reverse the first occurrence of subword*

Comment: На мой взгляд, задача довольно понятна: даны строка и подстрока, если подстрока есть в строке, то перевернуть первую из найденных подстрок и вывести изменённую строку, иначе вывести s без изменений. Единственное, к чему можно придраться — `reverse the first occurrence of s` — здесь должна быть `subword` вместо `s`, но сути это не меняет

Comment: Задачу в вузе дали.

Comment: `reversed` - встроенная функция питона, не используйте такое имя для переменной

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша функция `replace` будет заменять **все** вхождения заменяемой подстроки, не только первую. Чтобы ограничить число замен до 1, нужно использовать необязательный параметр функции [replace](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.replace/) под названием `maxcount`.